# Ellipsoid in spherical cordinates

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot in spherical coordinates the ellipsoid defined as

$$(x/3a)^2+(y/2a)^2+(z/4c)^2=1$$

This is my code:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], (1/3 Cos[u] Sin[v])^2 + 
    (1/2 Sin[u] Sin[v])^2 + (1/4 Cos[v])^2 == 1}, {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, -π, π}]
```

What am I doing wrong? No errors are displayed and an empty frame is all I see.

Comment: Doing `Solve[(1/3 Cos[u] Sin[v])^2 + (1/2 Sin[u] Sin[v])^2 + (1/4 Cos[v])^2 == 1, {u, v}]` will shed some light on the problem. Mathematica can't get solution there. May be needs some assumptions. Try Reduce to see.

Comment: The third element of the vector you use makes no sense. In this form, it'll evaluate to `True` or `False` (as it's an equality test with `==`), which doesn't bode well for plotting anything.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, the parametrization is a rescaling of spherical coordinates:

```
With[{a = 3, c = 2},
 ParametricPlot3D[{3 a Cos[u] Sin[v], 2 a Sin[u] Sin[v], 4 c Cos[v]},
   {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, -π, π}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]