# How to render a 3D ellipsoid with Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics3d

With `Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]`, I can render a uniform 3D sphere, but how can I render an ellipsoid? I would need to specify the rotation of the ellipsoid and the length of the main axes. The method should be reasonably fast to display around 100 of them at once.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33486/ellipsoid-in-spherical-cordinates)

Comment: Look up `GeometricTransformation`

Comment: This uses ContourPlot3D:  http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/Ellipsoid/

Comment: There is also an `Ellipsoid` function in the `MultivariateStatistics` package that I used [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21402/5), but it acts cranky at times...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can modify this if you need to specify the rotation in different ways, etc. As Simon Woods has suggested, probably the best way is to use `GeometricTransformation`.

```
 ellipsoid[a_, b_, center_?VectorQ, rotation_, around_?VectorQ] := Fold[
           GeometricTransformation,
           Sphere[],
           {ScalingTransform[{a, b, b}],
            RotationTransform[rotation, around],
            TranslationTransform[center]}]

 ellipsoid @@@ Table[{x, x, 10 {x, x, x}, x, {x, x, x}} /. x :> RandomReal[]
                     , {111}] // Graphics3D // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.347020,
> ```
>
> [image]

Comment: I had a slight wtf moment at all the x's - nice way to generate the data.

Comment: @SimonWoods uff I was afraid I've missed something :)

Comment: You can compose the transforms with `Dot` instead of `Fold`: `TranslationTransform[center].RotationTransform[rotation, around].ScalingTransform[{a, b, b}]`.  Very nice, +1!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks ;) and yes `Dot` looks clear and is about 3% faster than `Fold` on my pc.

Comment: `Dot[]` works, but `Composition[]` is the documented way to compose geometric transforms: `GeometricTransformation[Sphere[], Composition[TranslationTransform[center], RotationTransform[rotation, around], ScalingTransform[{a, b, b}]]]`

Answer (score 15):

Using `Sphere` with `Scale` and `Rotate` works too:

```
Graphics3D[Rotate[Scale[Sphere[], {5, 4, 2}, {0, 0, 0}], 60 Degree, {1, 2, 1}]]
```

[image]

The first triple is the scaling in the x,y,and z coordinates, the second triple is the translation, and the third triple is the axis about which to rotate. To generate a number of random ellipses:

```
x := RandomReal[];
Show[Table[Graphics3D[Rotate[Scale[Sphere[], {x, x, x}, {x i/6, x i/6, x i/6}], 
                      x, {x, x, x}], Boxed -> False], {i, 25}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

An alternative approach that generates explicit primitives instead of transformed ones uses the NURBS representation of a sphere, with all the appropriate transformations done to its control points to generate the ellipsoid:

```
myEllipsoid[dims : {_?Positive, _?Positive, _?Positive} : {1, 1, 1}, 
            center : (_?VectorQ) : {0, 0, 0}, 
            rot : {_, _?VectorQ} : {0, {1, 0, 0}}] := Block[{ctrlpts},
  ctrlpts = Composition[TranslationTransform[center], 
                        RotationTransform[Sequence @@ rot],
                        ScalingTransform[dims]] /@ 
            Outer[Append[#2 #1[[1]], #1[[2]]] &,
                  {{0, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}},
                  {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}}, 1];
            BSplineSurface[ctrlpts, SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> 2, 
                           SplineKnots -> {{0, 0, 0, 1/2, 1, 1, 1},
                                           {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1}}, 
                           SplineWeights -> Outer[Times, {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1},
                                                  {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1}]]]
```

Here's an example:

```
randomEllipsoid := myEllipsoid[RandomReal[1, 3], RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 3],
                               {RandomReal[{-π, π}], 
                                Normalize[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 3]]}]

BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "Legacy"]; 
            Graphics3D[Table[{ColorData[61, RandomInteger[{1, 9}]], randomEllipsoid},
                             {50}], Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]]
```

[image: some ellipsoids]

Answer (score 9):

Starting from version 10 there is documented `Ellipsoid` which is reasonably fast

```
Graphics3D[Ellipsoid @@@ RandomReal[1, {100, 2, 3}]]
```

[image]

For an arbitrary orientation you specify the weight matrix Σ as a second argument

```
randomEllipsoid[] := Module[{ℛ, \[ScriptCapitalS], p},
  ℛ = First@QRDecomposition@RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {3, 3}];
  \[ScriptCapitalS] = DiagonalMatrix@RandomReal[1, 3];
  p = RandomReal[10, 3];
  Ellipsoid[p, ℛ\[Transpose].\[ScriptCapitalS].ℛ]]

Graphics3D[Table[randomEllipsoid[], {100}]]
```

[image]

Here `ℛ` and `\[ScriptCapitalS]` are random rotation matrix and random scale matrix respectively.

Comment: Its only limitation is that it can only generate axis-aligned ellipsoids; `Rotate[]` is still needed for the arbitrary orientation.

Comment: @J.M. What about `Graphics3D[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {{5, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 5}}]]`? :)

Comment: Ah, missed that. :D One still has to recognize the SVD for this. Anyway: `First @ QRDecomposition @ RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {3, 3}]` is more compactly done as `Orthogonalize[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {3, 3}]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Sure, it is just a habit because it is [faster](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AD6cm.png) for big matrices.

Comment: That's funny… maybe it's worth a question?

Comment: @J.M. I just find that the timings are the same with `Method -> "Householder"` in `Orthogonalize`.

Comment: Ah, I think I see now; `Orthogonalize[]` is probably not using LAPACK (that is, its implementation of QR decomposition) by default for numerical matrices. (Gram-Schmidt?)

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would add after looking at this quite a bit later. The numbers you use to generate the random ellipsoid orientation are not truly random. You are missing a factor of $\pi/2$ in the 4th argument in the table.

When generating the table, use this instead to get truly random ellipsoids:

```
 ellipsoid @@@ Table[{x, x, 10 {x, x, x}, pi/2*x, {x, x, x}} /. x :> RandomReal[]
                     , {111}] // Graphics3D // AbsoluteTiming
```

All I added was a factor of $\pi$ in the 4th argument of ellipsoid in the table being generated. This will give you random radian values from $0$ to $\pi/2$.