# How to interpolate closed surface

Tags: interpolation, splines

With [`BSplineSurface`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineSurface.html), I was trying to interpolate data points belonging to a sphere, but unfortunately I don't get the right geometry closing:

```
r = 1;
step = 30 π /180 ;
pts = Table[
            r {Cos[Θ] Cos[Ψ], 
               Cos[Θ] Sin[Ψ], 
               Sin[Θ]},
            {Θ, 0, 2 π, step}, 
            {Ψ,   0,  π, step}
];
Graphics3D[{BSplineSurface[pts, SplineClosed -> {True, True}],
            Red, Point[#] & /@ pts}
]
```

[image: my attempt]

How can one get the right Spline-closing to get a sphere out of the interpolation?

Comment: So, what are your desiderata for your spline surface. As is, the question is way to broad. Btw.: "Nice" spline interpolation for surfaces with a topology different from a reactangle, cylinder, or torus are rather nontrivial.

Comment: I restrict myself to the sphere interpolation then first. Is it possible to get the "right" closing of the BSpline Surface to reproduce the sphere geometry?

Comment: Well, you get something that almost looks like a sphere with `r = 1;
step = 10 Pi/180;
pts = Most@
   Table[r {Cos[\[CapitalTheta]] Cos[\[CapitalPsi]], 
      Cos[\[CapitalTheta]] Sin[\[CapitalPsi]], 
      Sin[\[CapitalTheta]]}, {\[CapitalPsi], -Pi, Pi, 
     step}, {\[CapitalTheta], -Pi/2, Pi/2, step}];
Graphics3D[{BSplineSurface[pts, SplineClosed -> {True, False}], Red, 
  Point[#] & /@ pts}]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, a sphere has a very simple [NURBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline) representation. It can be easily built up from the NURBS circle of [Piegl and Tiller](https://doi.org/10.1109/38.35537). A *Mathematica* implementation goes like this:

```
mySphere[center : (_?VectorQ) : {0, 0, 0}, radius : _?NumericQ : 1] :=
  Block[{ctrlpts},
        ctrlpts = Composition[TranslationTransform[center],
                              ScalingTransform[ConstantArray[radius, 3]]] /@ 
        Outer[Append[#2 #1[[1]], #1[[2]]] &,
              {{0, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}},
              {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}}, 1];
        BSplineSurface[ctrlpts, SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> 2, 
                       SplineKnots -> {{0, 0, 0, 1/2, 1, 1, 1},
                                       {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1}}, 
                       SplineWeights -> Outer[Times, {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1},
                                              {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1}]]]
```

For example:

```
Graphics3D[mySphere[], Boxed -> False]
```

[image: NURBS sphere]

(I had used this [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99666) for generating ellipsoids.)